# Get value of JSON object in PHP variable

Tags: php, json, variables, object

I have the following JSON object:

```
[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
   0: Object
      category: Object
         0: "Value"
```

I was wondering how I could get 'Value' in a variable in PHP.
I thought category[0] would just do it but I get the following instead of 'Value':

```
 __proto__: Object
```

What should I do?

Comment: Do you mean you have a javascript object (or array of objects it might appear) you want to pass to PHP?  What you show is not JSON (JSON is nothing more than a serialization format).  What is the actual mechanism proposed for passing the data (i.e. AJAX call)?

Comment: [{"category":{"0":"Value"}   <   You mean this?

Comment: If that's how your JSON looks like it would be `$var = json_decode($json); $var[0]['category']['0']`

Comment: Mhm, I get 'null' instead of the value ..

Comment: oh wait, try without the '' on the second 0 - $var[0]['category'][0]. Can you paste a larger snipped of your php code?

Comment: Still null for some reason.

Comment: Can you paste a larger snipped of your php code?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40979/discussion-between-tsanyo-tsanev-and-anoniem-anoniem)

Answer (score 1):

You have to converts the JSON string into associative array, which is done by json_decode() with second parameter set as true.

```
$var = json_decode($json, true); 
$value = $var['0']['category']['0'];
```